# How to load html file inside cakephp using dompdf

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf-generation, cakephp-3.0, dompdf

I am using dompdf with cakephp 3.6 to generate prints from HTML to PDF

I have a function name **test** inside drivercontroller and i want to load a ctp file which is created inside src\Template\DriverDetails and filename is testpdf.ctp

Can u plz help me to suggest how to pass complete file.

Below is my code

```
public function test()  {
            $html = file_get_contents("testpdf.ctp");            
            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream("invoice.pdf", array("Attachment" =>0));
            exit(0);
        }
```

**src\Template\DriverDetails\testpdf.ctp**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td align="center"><?php echo $id; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center">Demo Data</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like that way.

```
public function test()
{
    $data = "This can be accessible in view file";
    $builder = $this->viewBuilder();
    $builder->autoLayout(false);

    // set your template path [don't use .ctp]
    $builder->template('Users/add');

    //Pass data into view file
    $view = $builder->build(['data' => $data]);

    //Render view file content and store into variable
    $viewContent = $view->render();
    var_dump($viewContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Put this inside controller method. $view_output is a variable where content of ctp file stored. "elements" is ctp file to render. In youur case it is testpdf

```
/* Make sure the controller doesn't auto render. */
 $this->autoRender = false;

/* Set up new view that won't enter the ClassRegistry */

$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set('text', 'Hello World');
$view->viewPath = 'elements';

/* Grab output into variable without */
$view_output = $view->render('box');
```

Here’s an example of storing the html of an element called ‘box’ with the variable of ‘text’ without the view displaying or outputting

[Here is an example](http://headynation.com/cakephp-get-htmloutput-of-view-without-view-displaying-or-outputting-using-render/)

Comment: I didn't get,,where to specify my filename and what to do with this code..can u please explain steps by steps process..

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.